# Why does compiling to ACCDE cause every form to throw reserved error -3034 on first open?

Tags: vba, database, forms, ms-access

So, I have an MS Access front-end that I'm compiling to an ACCDE, which I want to distribute. When running it from an ACCDB file, everything works fine. I have a welcome form with links to a bunch of different forms. Some I call with `DoCmd.OpenForm`, with others I create an instance of the form with `Set frm = New Form_Name`, and then show it with `frm.SetFocus` and `frm.Visible`. While testing and developing a number of different things, opening forms hasn't been a problem for what feels like an eternity.

But then I compiled the ACCDE, and for some reason, opening forms has stopped working. While the welcome form miraculously works just fine, opening any other forms from that welcome form generates an error 3000 with a description which is something along the lines of "reserved error (-3034); there is no message for this error" (might not be 100% accurate since I'm translating from German). This is regardless of if I call it with `DoCmd.OpenForm` or create a new instance.

Here's the weird part: this only ever happens once for every form after compiling. That means, if I launch the form again after the error, even after closing the front-end entirely, then it works. I've checked over and over again and there are no variables being used, so there isn't the chance of some variable being uninitialized. Now, I could just execute every form on the ACCDE file after compiling it, but that seems like a ridiculous workaround. Plus, it doesn't make any sense, either, since I'm not storing any data in the front-end.

And oddly enough, this happens with all forms except the welcome form. The welcome form is launched by a macro, but I've ruled that out, since some of the forms that I launch from the welcome form used to be launched with macros, and I had the same problem there. The biggest difference between the welcome form and the other forms is that the welcome form is an unbound form.

Oddly enough, Google has not led me to any people with the same problem. Has anyone else ever had this problem or know what could be causing it? This isn't only happening on my computer, in fact, I was alerted to the problem after I had distributed an alpha version of the front-end. I'm using Access on office 365, version 1908, in case it makes a difference.

Comment: I'm curious as to what happens if you re-link all your tables in the ACCDE before trying to open any forms.  Also it looks like 1908 is not the current version, perhaps try updating your Office install.

Comment: so with the accDB, in code editor, a debug->compile works ok? You then create the accDE, exit the accDB, and now launch the accDE you just created? This is all occurring on the same computer during testing?

Comment: @deluxeinformation by God, that worked. Now I just have to find a way to do it programmatically, so that I can turn off the menus etc. If you have any pointers as to that, that would be great, but thanks already for the great suggestion (and feel free to post this as an answer)!

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Yes to all that. It compiles correctly, and yes, on the same computer (and also on different computers).

Comment: @BenjaminKrausseDB I'm glad that worked for you and updating the connections in code might be a good short term workaround but it doesn't make sense to me that simply creating an .accde breaks your linked table connections.  Are you running the latest update for Office?

Comment: I could have sworn I sent the comment, I guess I didn't. I'm on my business computer, where we're on some sort of long term release branch or something, and I don't have any control over updates. The odd thing is, switching from macros to VBA actually fixed it for a while. Then it started happening again.

Comment: OK, interesting, it seems I only had to do it once on the uncompiled ACCDB file. Now, fingers crossed, it is possible to compile ACCDE files without any issues.